# Covert Hex value to string

Tags: c

I want to convert hex value to string in c.
Example:

```
a[4] = {0x34, 0x31, 0xF5, 0x43}
```

it need to convert as string

```
b[8] = {3431F543}
```

Comment: [Search, and Research.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I think `sprintf` will help you.

Comment: What sort of syntax is `b[8] = {3431F543} `?

Comment: [flip coin], OK 'too broad' this time.

Answer (score 1):

DevSolar's sprintf solution is good and easy. But I've come up with more optimized, hack version.

```
void convert_hex_4b_to_string(char buf[9], int ar[4])
{
    static const char tbl[] = "0123456789ABCDEF";
    buf[0] = tbl[((unsigned)ar[0] >> 4) & 0x0f];
    buf[1] = tbl[((unsigned)ar[0]) & 0x0f];
    buf[2] = tbl[((unsigned)ar[1] >> 4) & 0x0f];
    buf[3] = tbl[((unsigned)ar[1]) & 0x0f];
    buf[4] = tbl[((unsigned)ar[2] >> 4) & 0x0f];
    buf[5] = tbl[((unsigned)ar[2]) & 0x0f];
    buf[6] = tbl[((unsigned)ar[3] >> 4) & 0x0f];
    buf[7] = tbl[((unsigned)ar[3]) & 0x0f];
    buf[8] = '\0';
}
```

... under assumption that all integers are less than 0x100.

[(live example)](http://ideone.com/xNFM4s)